# how to draw multiple distribution

Tags: pandas

```
fig_dspl, axes_dspl = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(9, 4))
sns.distplot(df_08['displ'], ax = axes_dspl[0]) 
_ = axes_dspl[0].set_title('08')
sns.distplot(df_18['displ'], ax = axes_dspl[1])
_ = axes_dspl[1].set_title('18')
```

can anyone explain the detail of this code above?  especially the first line, is this for multiple graphs?   i understand how to draw a single plot (sis.displot), don't clearly understand the `ax = axes_dspl[0]`) ... and what the `_ = axes_dspl[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create two plots, get the figures and axes

```
fig_dspl, axes_dspl = plt.subplots(nrows=1, ncols=2, figsize=(9, 4))
```

In the first axes, draw a `seaborn.distplot`.

```
sns.distplot(df_08['displ'], ax = axes_dspl[0])
```

Set `'08'` as the title of this plot. Assign the result to `_` and ignore it (you may as well write `axes_dsp...` instead of `_ = axes_dsp...` in this case).

```
_ = axes_dspl[0].set_title('08')
```

Similarly do so for the second axes.

```
sns.distplot(df_18['displ'], ax = axes_dspl[1])
_ = axes_dspl[1].set_title('18')
```

In conclusion:

1. The first assignment (to the outcome of `distplots`) allows greater control of the result, in this case by setting the titles later on.
2. The later assignments (`_ = axes_dspl...`) are just moise and are better omitted.

Comment: thanks!  and i want to know what's the fig_dspl?  and if the axes_dspl is just a variable name that can be assigned as whatever i want?

Comment: You're welcome. `fig_dspl` is a [`Figure`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.figure.Figure.html#matplotlib.figure.Figure) object, but it's not used here, it seems. You can replace the variable name `axs_dspl` with any other legal Python identifier name.